# how to deploy/install a csr certificate in apache?

Tags: ssl

So, I bought an SSL Certificate from godaddy for one of my domains. it gave me one `generated-csr.txt` and `generated-private-key.txt`. I've been looking for a while on how to deploy a CSR certificate, but couldn't find any that is understandable. Even godaddy itself uses the `.crt` format in their tutorial

Also they uses `SSLCertificateChainFile`  which I don't if I am suppose to chain my private key and csr to get this or what?

URL: https://au.godaddy.com/help/manually-install-an-ssl-certificate-on-my-apache-server-centos-5238

Can someone explain, how do I deploy my certificate manually to apache2?

Comment: *"... it gave me one generated-csr.txt and generated-private-key.txt ..."* - this is not sufficient.If this is all you have it looks like you are not fully complete with the certificate generation yet and that's why you are stuck which files you cannot use. See also [Purchased SSL Cert but can't attach to a website](https://serverfault.com/questions/1055830/purchased-ssl-cert-but-cant-attach-to-a-website) which describes exactly the same problem.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, You were right, I still had to click continue button. Anyway, I got three more files, `somerandomestring.crt`, `somerandomestring.pem` and `gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt`. I tried to configure them under my apche config, but i seem to fail on provide the correct values for SSL CertificateFile, Key, Chain. Can you help how to sort them and what values are to be pushed in which variable?

Comment: see for example https://www.tothenew.com/blog/commercial-ssl-certificate-apache/ for instructions.

Comment: That is exactly what I did but was getting this error `SSL Library Error: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch`, the private key is `generated-private-key.txt` or `domainprivate.key` after renaming the file

Comment: This error suggests that the key does not match the certificate. Unfortunately, I have no idea of what you are doing in the exact detail, I have no idea of the contents of the files and so I cannot really suggest what exactly you are doing wrong and how to fix it. I can only explain what the cause of the errors might be and you have to figure out the rest yourself.